# Calling a private method in the controller returns a null value

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to delete a post but whenever I delete a post its tag is not deleted. I'm using breakpoint to see how things happening and I noticed that GetPost doesn't include the tag whenever it is called. In my codes below you can see that i'm trying to insert/call tagg in the delete method but seems cannot call it.

**My Delete in the Controller**

```
   public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            if (IsUser)
            {
                Post post = GetPost(id);
                var tagss = db.Tags.Where(tg => tg.ID == id); // this should call GetTag but i dunno how :(
                foreach (var t in tagss)
                {
                    db.Tags.DeleteObject(t);
                }

                db.DeleteObject(post);
                db.SaveChanges();                   
            }
            return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
        }
```

**GetPost**

```
 private Post GetPost(int? id)
        {
            return id.HasValue ? db.Posts.Where(x => x.ID == id).First() : new Post() { ID = -1 };           
        }
```

**GetTag**

```
private Tag GetTag(string tagName)
        {
            return db.Tags.Where(x => x.Name == tagName).FirstOrDefault() ?? new Tag() { Name = tagName };
        }
```

**Problem:**
I trying to include the tag in the delete function so that whenever i delete my post it will also be deleted but i dont know how to call it. pls help me guys thank sorry im not good in querying. :(
**update:**

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            if (IsUser)
            {
                Post post = GetPost(id);
                var tagss = var taggs = post.Tags;
                foreach (var t in tagss)
                {
                    db.Tags.DeleteObject(t);
                }

                db.DeleteObject(post);
                db.SaveChanges();                   
            }
            return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
        }
```

I was now able to call the tag list but still not able to delete it with my post. This gives me an error **Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.**

Comment: What properties does your Post object have?

Comment: I don't see any line in your code that calls the GetTag method, or is that what you wanted to ask?

Comment: @Hanno yeah your right that is what I wanted to ask because I dunno how to call it Im doing it on a wrong way. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I was now able to delete my tags I just added .ToList and the error goes away. Here's my working one.

```
 public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            if (IsUser)
            {
                Post post = GetPost(id);
                var taggs = post.Tags;
                foreach (var t in tagss.ToList())
                {
                    db.Tags.DeleteObject(t);
                }

                db.DeleteObject(post);
                db.SaveChanges();                   
            }
            return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your problem correctly you could maybe amend your Post class to contain a property called "Tags" which is a collection of your Tag class and contains all the tag names for that post, then you could do something like this to get the tags for that post and then delete them.

```
Post post = GetPost(id);
var tagss = post.Tags;
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and I'm already one step away to accomplish it because I was now able to call the list but still it's not deleting. see my updated answer of what I tried. sorry Im noob.. :(

Comment: It gives me an erro "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."